# SQL Azure HierarchyId support?

Tags: azure-sql-database, hierarchyid

I was wondering if anyone could confirm for certain whether SQL Azure supports hierarchy nodes and how comparable it is to SQL 2008's Hierarchy ID in terms of performance/scalability.

Basically we are looking at migrating a system that makes extensive use of the existing HierarchyId's in very performance-critical methods and the support for this feature is a massive game-changer for the project but I don't have access to an SQL Azure database to test this myself currently.

I have found some reference to it as part of SQL Azure SU3 released in 2010, but at the same time I have contradictions from Microsoft where they've essentially said it's not supported in SQL Azure (Directly as opposed to an official announcement, unfortunately not directly to me so I couldn't question it like I'd have wanted to)...

I was hoping someone with a bit of experience with Azure could let me know which side is true, and if the feature exists whether the performance is comparable to in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: What kinds of operations are you interested in? We only make small use of the HierarchyId type in our Azure project (for sorting software build versions) like `order by cast('/' + replace(Version, '.', '/') + '/' as hierarchyid)`
So the type should be there but I don't have experience what you could do with it ..

Comment: Primarily using it for the IsDescendantOf method (There is more that we use, but if that one still worked we could probably work around the rest). We're using it mostly for the performance it gives for querying massive dynamic tree structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SQL Azure supports hierarchyid as a data type and the related functions. For a description of which functions are supported, [see this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336233.aspx). Go towards the end of the article for the hierarchy data type.

No matter what the official documentation says, you should absolutely try your database schema against a SQL Azure database. Creating an Azure account takes a few seconds and figuring out if your database schema is compatible is pretty easy too.

However I wonder what you mean by running "performance-critical operations". You should probably test SQL Azure from a performance standpoint to make sure you are getting what you need out of it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks like it has what we need. By performance-critical operations I mean I'm working on a multi-gigabyte database and the HierarchyId IsDescendantOf filtering in our queries is very common - to the point where for example subsituting a recursive CTE for some of them makes the database server grind 100% CPU until timeout to achieve the exact same result. We definitely intend to do some performance testing of our own, I was just hoping to get some high-level assurances before we invest enough to even test the performance - at this stage moving it is just a possible idea.